# Can’t create cc.ProgressTimer instance in Cocos Creator project

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

This article says, ProgressTimer preserved it's behavior while migration to Cocos Creator:
http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/editors_and_tools/creator-chapters/getting-started/cocos2d-x-guide/2

So, I tried to create ProgressTimer from code with both:

```
var obj1 = new cc.ProgressTimer(sprite); // -> cc.ProgressTimer is not a constructor
```

and

```
var obj2 = cc.ProgressTimer.create(sprite); // -> Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

code lines and as you see nothing is working for me.

I'm using Cocos Creator 1.4.

I can't even find CCProgressTimer.js inside CocosCreator directory.
Also, I can't find CCClippingNode.js(which is also listed in preserved nodes list on Cocos Creator docs). But there is still CCSprite.js file presented. What am I missed up?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Progress Bar and do the timer yourself. Also you should read the API for the version of Cocos Creator that you are using. Many things change from version to version.
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/creator/v1.5/classes/ProgressBar.html